# Can I disable processor drivers

Tags: 14.04, gnome-terminal, cpu

My Toshiba laptop freezes when I plug in the AC Power cord.I fix this problem in windows 7 by going into Safe Mode then Control Panel > Device Manager > Processors and disable both of them.
What I am disabling is the processor driver actually thus preventing the processor from going into C or P states. The problem is, whenever the processor goes in power management or downclocks, the system freezes and shows colorful horizontal or vertical lines.
I want to try ubuntu but I don't know how to disable processor drivers .
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux has a quite different architecture to Windows and the equivalent of what you are doing is not to "disable a driver".

You do have some runtime control over processor C states.  Writing "0" to `/dev/cpu_dma_latency` effectively disables all C states according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22482252/how-to-set-intel-idle-max-cstate-0-to-disable-c-states) although you may also get what you want by adding `intel_idle.max_cstate=0` as a kernel boot parameter (eg on your kernel command line in grub).

Note that doing this is only a workaround for a hardware fault.  If your processor is unstable enough to change C states without crashing, you may experience other serious issues.  Is it excessively overclocked?

Comment: I agree, this sounds like a hardware issue. May be there is a firmware/bios update that fixes this. Release information published along with updates for Thinkpads and ProBooks at least contain some information and are worth a read.